# Неполный перевод на главной странице

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, целевая-аудитория

На главной странице, если юзер ещё не авторизован. Часть вступительного текста на английском, часть на русском. В частности такой текст: `Stack Overflow на русском is a question and answer for программистов (sic!)`. Возможно правильным будет строка "Stack Overflow на русском это вопросы и ответы для программистов".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И текст "Отправить" на кнопке тоже смущает.

Comment: "Q&A Site" != "вопросы и ответы".

Comment: @Qwertiy да да, это я так систему пытался водой обмануть, иначе не принимался один скришнот