# Расширить описание сайта в выпадающем меню и сделать его согласованным с сайтами SO на других языках

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация, целевая-аудитория

На сегодня в выпадающем меню со списком сайтов SE для группы сайтов SO выводятся такие однострочные описания:

> [image: SO international]

Можно заметить, что у нас описание несколько ограниченное по сравнению с другими SO. Предлагаю всё же это исправить. Варианты можно обсудить, например, такие:

1. Для профессиональных программистов и энтузиастов
2. Для профессиональных программистов и любителей
3. Для программистов любых уровней

Несколько пересекающихся вопросов по данной ситуации уже помечены как решённые:

- [«Q&A for программистов»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4040/176217)
- [Целевая аудитория сайтов Stack Exchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3680/176217)
- [Неполный перевод на главной странице](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3493/176217)

Comment: 3 логически больше всего подходит, потому что в 2 непонятно любители чего, а в 1 - энтузиасты чего

Comment: И ещё непонятно, почему только программисты, когда [администраторы тоже приветствуются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6214/394322)

Comment: @вася возможно, действительно для ruSO надо сделать более общее описание, т.к. у нас онтопик немного шире того, что на enSO.